# Unable to open the Operamini browser in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am unable t download the opera mini browser driver , like How we can follow the chrome browser. can u please provide the link . so its useful to work and open the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium webdriver don't support opera-mini (but I hope it will change.

For the moment if you want to test OperaMini on your computer for testing purpose you need to use MicroEmulator :
[Installing Opera Mini on your computer](https://dev.opera.com/articles/installing-opera-mini-on-your-computer/)

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

There is no OperaDriver exe to download( like for Chrome/IE).
You just need the Selenium jar file to instantiate opera driver instance. Please refer [this link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver) to get more details on Opera Driver